# use v-model with a map of arrays where key is a number

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have this map here :

```js
data() {
  return {
    secondarySkillHistory: {
      "1": [1, 2, 4],
      "5": [1, 7, 5]
    }
  };
},
```

I want to add the array in map "1" to my v-model of my checkbox:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  :id="secondarySkill.catId"
  :name="secondarySkill.catName"
  :value="secondarySkill.catId"
  v-model="secondarySkillHistory.1" <!-- doesnt work -->
/>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access that property using `[]` (the bracket notation) like :

```
 v-model="secondarySkillHistory['1']"
```

or

```
 v-model="secondarySkillHistory[1]"
```

since the key is a number

check [`property accessors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for more details